# Linux routing issue with two nics

Tags: networking, routing

I have a Server (SERVER1) with two network interfaces, as shown in the diagram.  I have another Server (SERVER2) from which I am trying to connect to SERVER1.

When I connect to eth0 (10.0.0.124) I succeed. However, when i connect to eth1 (10.0.15.213) I fail.

I suspect it is down to the routing table on SERVER1 whereby SERVER1 receives the signal on eth1 but routes the response down eth0, thus breaking the TCP communication chain.

So how can I tell the routing table to respond down the same network interface that it received the connection on, but nothing is being sent back?

[image]

To further this, a tcpdump of the connection on SERVER1 shows the following, which shows SERVER2 is making the connection:

```
# tcpdump -i eth1 -n
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
06:01:35.543172 IP 10.0.2.109.51554 > 10.0.15.213.22: Flags [S], seq 1526846784, win 26883, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 311066 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
06:01:36.540677 IP 10.0.2.109.51554 > 10.0.15.213.22: Flags [S], seq 1526846784, win 26883, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 311316 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
06:01:38.544674 IP 10.0.2.109.51554 > 10.0.15.213.22: Flags [S], seq 1526846784, win 26883, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 311817 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
06:01:42.556548 IP 10.0.2.109.51554 > 10.0.15.213.22: Flags [S], seq 1526846784, win 26883, options [mss 8961,sackOK,TS val 312820 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

A netstat when connected to eth0

```
# netstat -tnp
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0    280 10.0.0.124:22           10.0.2.109:54298        ESTABLISHED 8562/sshd: ubuntu [
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many strange things in this setup.
You omitted important information about the devices with 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.2.1. Presumably they are on the same device, a router between the networks. Without a router between your machines, they would not be able to reach either interface.

You can start diagnosing with pings. Use tcpdump on the interfaces `eth1`, `eth0` and `all`. I suspect you will find out the the responses are sent back via eth0 but don't arrive at your server2. Use tcpdump or something equivalent on your router.

Answer (score 1):

Short lived question as I found another thread [[1]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/reply-on-same-interface-as-incoming) with the answer.

From what I understand, it creates a rule that says "if traffic from 10.0.15.213 then route it back down itself"

```
echo 200 nic2 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add from 10.0.15.213 table nic2
ip route add default via 10.0.15.1 dev eth1 table nic2
```

Comment: This works because it causes the responses to use eth1 instead of eth0. It seems your router cares about that. It probably runs a firewall with connection tracking.

Comment: It's Amazon Web Services...